# UseEffect does not rerender when remove data out of an array only upon adding data does it rerender

Tags: reactjs, arrays, local-storage, splice

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { HiOutlineBackspace } from "react-icons/hi";
import {MdOutlineCancel} from 'react-icons/md'

const Cart = ({toggleCart}) => {
  const localStorageCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MY_CART')) || []
  const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState(localStorageCart)
*************************************  
  const handleDeleteButton = (index) => {
    cartItem.filter(cartItem[index])
    console.log(cartItem);
  }
**************************************
  useEffect(() =>{
    setCartItem(cartItem)
  },[cartItem])

  return (
    <div className='cartContainer'>
      <h1 style={{textAlign:"center"}}>Your Cart</h1>     
      <button 
      style={{backgroundColor:'transparent'}}
      onClick={toggleCart}
      >
        <HiOutlineBackspace/>
      </button>

      <div className='cartCardContainer'>  
      {cartItem.map((cartItem,index) =>{
        return(
          <div className="cartCard" key={index}>
            <img src={cartItem.img} alt="logo" id="img" />
            <h2>{cartItem.title}</h2>

            <div className="description">
              <h5>{cartItem.description}</h5>
            </div>

            <div className="priceCard"  >
              <h3>${cartItem.price}</h3>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => handleDeleteButton(index)}>***********************
              <MdOutlineCancel/>
            </button>
        </div>
        )
      })}
        
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

I am working on an e-commerce add to Cart function.

By using useEffect I managed to rerender the cart right upon adding an item since it was a one-page app.

But when I tried to splice( ) the cartItem I heard that it is not a good practice and that I should use filter( ) instead but I am having trouble doing so as I have tried many ways and the filter doesn't go as planned or it just dont run.

For this part of the project I use a lot of Local Storage as it is the addToCart component

I have put ***** symbol on where I think the problem might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering is not implemented correctly. Also, you have to update the state after filtering/removing items from the state.

You can use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove an element from an array.

The following is how `handleDeleteButton` should look like:

```js
const handleDeleteButton = (index) => {
  cartItem.splice(index, 1)); // 1 means remove one item only
  setCartItem([...cartItem]);
}
```

Comment: Hey Moradi, thanks for the answer. It work perfectly in the UI, the delete button did work, and when I console.log(cartItem) it did give me the new array, but it wouldn't change the array that is existing in the LocalStorage. Meaning after I reset the page the Cart would just be the same.

Comment: @BennyBach If you want to update the localStorage you need to call the `setItem` method on the localStorage object and provide the `key` and `value` accordingly. Add the following to the end of `handleDeleteButton`: `localStorage.setItem('MY_CART', JSON.Stringify([...cartItem]));`

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you very much, Mr.Mehrdad thanks for understanding and solving my question, much is appreciated, and I will mark the question as solved. You are a very talented dev sir!!

Answer (score 2):

The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method returns a new array based on the condition you provide it. So in your code you're not actually altering the state of your `cartItem`.

Filter your `cartItem` array and use the return value to set your `cartItem` state.

```
const handleDeleteButton = (index) => {
    setCartItem(cartItem.filter(...));
}
```

As a side note, you would be better filtering your items by a key or identifier associated with the item rather than the index value of your  map function.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that many people are suggesting using an id as a key but I have been using the index and it's been kinda working, and many of the error I have encountered luckily hasn't been related to using index value.

Comment: And I did notice that Splice would alternate your original array. While  using filter, we would need to assign the new array to a new Variable.

Comment: @BennyBach Yeah so the use of `filter` or `splice` is down to you really. There isn't much (if any) difference in performance. The main difference being `filter` returns a shallow copy of the array matching the test condition provided, vs amending the array. You don't need to assign `filter` to a new variable, you can pass it directly to your state `setter`.

Answer (score 1):

useEffect woke when you are updating the state your state now is `cartItem`,
To update this state most be execute `setCartItem` well in your function well you must do this :

```
setCartItem(cartItem.splice(cartItem[index],1)
```

I do not know what is inside your array `cartItem` well do you filter and change it with `setCartItem`

Comment: And what will be set to the state with that code?

Comment: bro you have to do your filter alone because we do not how inside in your array ( if this code doesn't work ) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
this URL is for arrays in js and you can do some test there is many functions for manage arrays

Comment: Nope, Im just pointing that `splice` method returns `An array containing the deleted elements` and you are settign this array of deleted element to the state.

Comment: well then change your function array ... go to the URL I give you and do some simulation of your array ... it's simple you have just learning how arrays functions works

Comment: I know how this works, to be honest, and im trying to point you that the code you wrote will set the state of `cartItems` to the array that is returned by `splice` method. Splice modifies the array AND it returns another array, the array of deleted elements. SO your answer is incorrect.

Comment: `const copyCartItem = cartItem.slice(index + 1)
setCartItem(copyCartItem)`
do this

Comment: oh so you mean by just doing  setCart(cartItem.Slice(index+1)) is not optimal? Is better to assign the new array to a new Variable right can you elaborate a little more please I would love to know more.